Closed token accounts still exists in account database snapshot
I have downloaded and extracted the account database snapshot file like: snapshot-299540607-sWVaMpWgjXC8vdN9uKzP8Fo99DRQNyQWsoxA7W1Nwon.tar.zst using solana-snapshot-etl.
This snapshot was taken at slot 299540607, but it still contains token accounts (with amount > 0 and state = 1) which were closed at before slot. For example: token account 8dsgqukRvZgsmLUNWaERsNeHmDC9smnF6ud3N9WTKhoy was closed at slot 299395132.
Could anyone help me? Thanks.
